# R lagging a dataframe

Tags: r, sum, time-series, lag

I am new to R and I have a problem with lagging an operation.

These are my data frames.

```
Stock_Returns

Date          Stock_A       Stock_B    
01.01.1990    NA            NA          
01.02.1990    0.02          0.04        
01.03.1990    0.03          0.05        
01.04.1990    0.04          0.06        

Market_Cap

Date          Stock_A       Stock_B      Sum
01.01.1990    30            30           60
01.02.1990    20            35           55
01.03.1990    30            50           80
01.04.1990    40            60           100
```

I want to have the sumproduct of Stock_Returns and Market_Cap (with a lag of -**one**) and then divide it with the Market_Cap$Sum (with lag of -**one**).

This is my code with **no lag**! I need a lag of -1

```
Index <- rowSums(Returns[,2:ncol(Returns)]*(Market_Cap[,3:ncol(Market_Cap)-1]),na.rm=TRUE)/Market_Cap$Sum
```

My output should look like this:

```
Index_Return

Date          Index        
01.01.1990    NA                       
01.02.1990    0.03              
01.03.1990    0.0427           
01.04.1990    0.0525
```

The calculation for the 01.02.1990 would be (0.02*30+0.04*30)/60

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to achieve your desired output by use of row numbers. We select a subset of rows in the first table with indices n, and then in the second table a subset of rows with indices n-1.

```
Index <- rowSums(Returns[2:nrow(Returns), 2:ncol(Returns)] * Market_Cap[2:nrow(Returns)-1, 3:ncol(Market_Cap)-1], na.rm = T) / Market_Cap[2:nrow(Returns)-1, "Sum"]
```

Then we can append it to Returns:

```
Returns$Index[2:nrow(Returns)] <- Index
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This works perfectly for me!